# Do facebook user has to grant permissions separately on multiple platforms?

Tags: android, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I used login with facebook in the website. Now I have developed the app for the same. Do users of website will have to grant permissions again while login with facebook in android app ?

I know that facebook only provide list of friends who already granted permission to our app. But I am not getting list of user's friends who have already granted permission on the web. Do they need to login with facebook using android app again ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same App ID, then they do not need to re-grant permissions.

They will need to either login in again on the Android app, or you can supply the Android app with the access token from your website, and use that to make the friends requests.